# rename file in Python: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to rename a file in a folder and i keep getting the error that the file is not there....

```
import os
import time
from os.path import isfile, join


working_dir = ('C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop')
only_file = [f for f in os.listdir(working_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(working_dir, f))]
print only_file

time_srt = time.strftime("%d_%m_%Y")

if 'EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx' in only_file:
    os.rename('EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx', "EZShift_" + time_srt + ".xlsx")
```

> C:\Python27\python.exe 
>   C:/Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/Paython/Python3/pbx.py
>   ['xxxxxx.jpg', 'xxxx.zip', 'xxxx.xlsx', 'xxx.pdf', 'xxx.MOV', 'xx.MOV', 'xxxxx_18_12_2016.xlsx', 'EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx','Test_EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx']
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/sabaja/Desktop/Paython/Python3/pbx.py", line 24, in 
>       os.rename('EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx', "EZShift_" + time_srt + ".xlsx")
>   **WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified**

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your filenames from `os.listdir` are *relative paths* (`os.listdir` returns the filenames onla); they will be searched for in your current working directory which is `os.getcwd()` (that will not be changed just because you name a variable `working_dir`)

you need to [`os.path.join(working_dir, filename)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to get *absolute paths* in order to access (and rename) your files.

you could do something like this:

```
import os.path

if 'EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx' in only_file:
    old_path = os.path.join(working_dir, "EZShift_WeeklyPerDayScheduleReport_Export.xlsx")
    new_path = os.path.join(working_dir, "EZShift_" + time_srt + ".xlsx")
    os.rename(old_path, new_path)
```